# getting the \to symbol in LaTex into ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, plot, latex, ggplot2

I am attempting to get the following expression into the tick marks of my `ggplot2`: `x \to y` where `\to` is the usual latex arrow symbol.  what is the right way to do this? `expression(x%to%y)` does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

`%->%`

eg

```
plot(1, type='n')
text(1,1, expression(x %->%y))
```

[image]

The various arrows are described in `?plotmath`

```
x %<->% y      # x double-arrow y
x %->% y       # x right-arrow y
x %<-% y       # x left-arrow y
x %up% y       # x up-arrow y
x %down% y     # x down-arrow y
x %<=>% y      # x is equivalent to y
x %=>% y       # x implies y
x %<=% y       # y implies x
x %dblup% y    # x double-up-arrow y
x %dbldown% y  #     x double-down-arrow y
```

If you want *real* LaTex, then you could attempt to get [tikzDevice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/index.html) working for your version of `R`